# Issue with output list for learnyounode #6 MAKE IT MODULAR

Tags: javascript, node.js

Just started coding last thursday, bear with me here:

my code for this question of the tutorial is returning a list of just the extension names from the directory and not a list of the files with the said extension, e.g. if i used a directory with 3 .js files and used js as my extension argument in the command line, then i would get
1. js
2. js
3. js
as the output, here is the question from the tutorial and my code. THANK YOU!

the question from learnyounode tutorial number 6:

- LEARN YOU THE NODE.JS FOR MUCH WIN!
  ─────────────────────────────────────
  MAKE IT MODULAR
  Exercise 6 of 13

This problem is the same as the previous but introduces the concept of modules. You will need to create two files to solve this.

Create a program that prints a list of files in a given directory, filtered by the extension of the files. The first argument is the directory name and the second argument is the extension filter. Pr
int the list of files (one file per line) to the console. You must use asynchronous I/O.

You must write a module file to do most of the work. The module must export a single function that takes three arguments: the directory name, the filename extension string and a callback function, in
 that order. The filename extension argument must be the same as was passed to your program. i.e. don't turn it into a RegExp or prefix with "." or do anything else but pass it to your module where y
ou can do what you need to make your filter work.

The callback function must be called using the idiomatic node(err, data) convention. This convention stipulates that unless there's an error, the first argument passed to the callback will be null, a
nd the second will be your data. In this case, the data will be your filtered list of files, as an Array. If you receive an error, e.g. from your call to  fs.readdir(), the callback must be called wi
th the error, and only the error, as the first argument.

You must not print directly to the console from your module file, only from your original program.

In the case of an error bubbling up to your original program file, simply check for it and print an informative message to the console.

These four things are the contract that your module must follow.

- Export a single function that takes exactly the arguments described.
- Call the callback exactly once with an error or some data as described.
- Don't change anything else, like global variables or stdout.
- Handle all the errors that may occur and pass them to the callback.

The benefit of having a contract is that your module can be used by anyone who expects this contract. So your module could be used by anyone else who does learnyounode, or the verifier, and just work. *

and my code is: 
module (p6m.js):

```
 var fs=require('fs'), ph=require('path'), exports =module.exports={}

 exports.f=function(path,ext,callbk){

 fs.readdir(path,function(err,files){

    if(err){
         return callbk(err,null)
    } 

   files=files.filter(

    function(file){

    return ph.extname(file)==="."+ext
        }
    ) 
    return callbk(null,files)} 
)}
```

and my program (p6.js):

```
   var p6m=require('./p6m'), path=process.argv[2], ext=process.argv[3]

p6m.f(path, ext, function(err,files){

if(err){return console.log.error('Error occured:', err)}; 

  files.forEach(function(file){

    console.log(file)})})
```

Comment: NVM, its still not working.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem with my code as of need to use a **single function** **export** . So instead of exporting a module function like this :

```
exports =module.exports={}

 exports.f=function(path,ext,callbk){...};
```

try it doing this way :

```
module.exports = function (path, ext, callbk) {...};
```

because its a single function so you don't need to specify that function with a name " f " as if you are doing it in this statement :

exports.***f*** = function(path,ext,callbk){...};

whenever you will import the module,it will automatically call this function only, since the module contains this single function.

You can try this piece of code, it works well for me.

module code: **mymodule.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ph= require('path');
module.exports = function (path, ext, callbk) {
var pathio = "." + ext;
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
        if (err)
            return callbk(err);
        else {
            var listf = []; //listf is the resultant list
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (ph.extname(files[i]) === pathio) {
                    listf.push(files[i]);
                }
 }
            callbk(null, listf);
     }

    });
}
```

program code : **moduletest.js**

```
var mod = require('./mymodule');
mod(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], function (err, listf) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error!')
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < listf.length; i++) {
            console.log(listf[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

and do remember, **learnyounode** series is very specific about its way of coding and syntax, so even if you are doing the logic right way still you won't get pass,you need your code to be the best and optimized. I'll suggest you to refer to discussions on nodeschool itself for various issues you might get in learnyounode series.

Answer (score 0):

That will work and output the right results, but what they are looking for is something like this:

```
module.exports =  function() {};
```

Because they only want one function total in the exports.

You could also do something like this:

```
module.exports =  FindFilesByExtension;

function FindFilesByExtension(path, ext, callback) {
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution,

Thsi is my module file **filteredls.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function filterFiles(folder, extension, callback) {
    fs.readdir(folder, function(err, files) {
        if(err) return callback(err);

        var filesArray = [];
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            if(path.extname(file) === "."+extension) {
                filesArray.push(file);
            }       
        });     
        return callback(null, filesArray);
    });
}
```

And here is my test file for reading module **modular.js**

```
var ff = require('./filteredls.js');

ff(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], function(err, data) {
    if(err)
        return console.error(err);
    data.forEach(function(file) {
        console.log(file);      
    }); 
});
```

And this is my result screenshot,

[image]